# Grails Export Plugin - Export Div Content and not a class list like in the docs

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, export, pdf-generation

after installing the grails export plugin
and adding

`<r:require module="export"/>`

`<export:resource />`

to my GSP with the final goal to render the containing DiV/table Contents to PDF.

*--- There are no classes rendered it is just a due javascript dyamically generated calculation table for a payment process, so the user can print the payment-summary as pdf to his local filesystem before submitting a payment form. ---*

adding the Buttonset:

```
<export:formats formats="['csv', 'excel', 'ods', 'pdf', 'rtf', 'xml']" />
```

and removing all unused array elements except `'pdf'`

in the controller  `def exportService` was added sucessfully.

in the docs the following example is given:

```
def list = {
    if(!params.max) params.max = 10

    if(params?.format && params.format != "html"){
        response.contentType = grailsApplication.config.grails.mime.types[params.format]
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=books.${params.extension}")
exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,Book.list(params), [:], [:])
    }

    [ bookInstanceList: Book.list( params ) ]
}
```

and for now i cannot adapt this to my use-case of contents of a table/div.
feel free to downvote if this is trivial and then drop a hint for my thinking to solve this.

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The export plugin 'exports' the data you explicitly want. So in the given example a Book.list(params) dataset is fed to the export plugin in order to export it. So i you want to export only a specific div / table on your page you have to feed the export plugin the data you want.

Creating a button on your page that is able to generate the dataset in the controller and feed that dataset to the export plugin would be a solution.